both shift key randomly working or not working
My laptop has a weird issue - recently the shift keys are working on a random basis. it means sometimes they are working normally sometimes the laptop does not recognize any input when using the shift key + key. my first thought was a hardware error of the keyboard. but then i recognized that it affects both shift keys (left and right). Since they are so far from each other and i never ever used the right shift key i think its a software issue. i already checked the keyboard settings - it is not the function sticky keys. i checked with xev and the output is the following [at the moment when they are working]:
left shift key

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x3c6, subw 0x0, time 1609822, (127,183), root:(307,347),
state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False


KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x3c6, subw 0x0, time 1609932, (127,183), root:(307,347),
state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False

right shift key

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x3c6, subw 0x0, time 1786581, (148,182), root:(328,346),
state 0x0, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False


KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
root 0x3c6, subw 0x0, time 1786696, (148,182), root:(328,346),
state 0x1, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False

I found it a bit weird that the keypress and release is both serial number 37 on the left, and on the right side the keypress is serial number 34 and the keyrelease is serial number is 37, maybe there is the mistake...
interestingly i also found out that if i press both shift keys and a letter the keyboard input inserts numbers [i.e. if i press both shiftkeys and the letter h the output is "8h"]. i am totally confused and seek for help. i need to study and write...
ubuntu 20.04 - asus laptop
